# Tablelayout with selectable rows

Tags: android, android-listview, google-tv, android-gridview, android-tablelayout

I have a dynamically populated TableLayout.

I'm developing for GoogleTV so I need to make the rows in the TableLayout selectable by the remote D-Pad. How can I achieve that?

Am I using the wrong approach here? Should I use a GridView instead? Or maybe ListView Adapter?

I've tried to find examples and similar questions but without success.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the rows user selectable (and clickable)?

I don't know what do you understand by selectable. To make it clickable just add a `OnClickListener` to each of your `TableRows`. To visually signal the user that the row is clickable(like a `Button` does it when it's pressed) then use a selector drawable for the `TableRow`'s background.

> Am I using the wrong approach here? Should I use a GridView instead?
>   Or maybe ListView Adapter?

A `GridView` no, but a `ListView` is a good candidate. If the table doesn't increase past the size you mention(10 x 3) you could use a simple `TableLayout`. If you know the `TableLayout` is likely to need to be scrolled(if it needs to be in a `ScrollView`) then a `ListView` will be more efficient.

Comment: The selectable part I referred is because I'm developing for GoogleTV and the user navigates with the remote D-Pad, so I need the row to be highlighted so the user knows where he stands. Thanks for your answer, I think will give ListView a try!